# pagination add in plugin

Tags: plugins, pagination

i have created pagination but it showed
WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '22 LIMIT -4, 4' at line 1]
22 LIMIT -4, 4

```
if (isset( $_GET['page'])){
    $page= ((int)$_GET['page']);
}
else{
    $page=1;
}
$items_per_page = 4;
$offset = ( $page * $items_per_page ) - $items_per_page;
$query  = "SELECT * FROM $table_name";
$total_query= "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (${query}) AS combined_table";
$total   = $wpdb->get_var( $total_query );
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $total . " LIMIT ${offset}, ${items_per_page}" );
$totalPage = ceil($total / $items_per_page);
```

Comment: `22 LIMIT -4, 4` is not an SQL query. You need to pass a complete query to `get_results()`.

Comment: i have passed query again it showd WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-4, 4' at line 1]